# Method to create sequence of rationals converging to irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this a mathematically valid method of creating a sequence of rationals that converges to an irrational, or is it a handwaving argument?

I know that I could create a sequence by actually giving a formula.

Let $x$ be an irrational. Choose rationals between $x-1/n$ and $x+1/n$ for all $n$.

I find it a bit suspicious because I'm not specifying clearly what rational I'll be choosing. I can't say choose the smallest/largest.

Comment: I think you mean "between $x$ and $x-(1/n)$". It's valid as an existence proof. It's not valid as a constructive proof. Do you want to know more about that? or do you want to see a constructive proof?

Comment: You can use the sequence $\lfloor nx-1\rfloor/n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I meant that. I don't understand why this sequence valid because a sequence has to be a bijection between Natural Numbers and the terms of the sequence, and I'm not actually pinpoint where each natural number is going.

Comment: It is, as I wrote, valid as an existence proof – it shows that such a sequence exists. It's not valid as a constructive proof, as it doesn't actually construct the sequence for you. Mathematics is full of non-constructive existence proofs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the choice of some rational number between $x-\frac{1}{n}$ and $x+\frac{1}{n}$ is equally valid and works fine.

Comment: @Thomas, sure, though I don't think OP will like it, as it's not constructive. Ah, I see, you didn't see the problem before OP edited it, when it just said, "choose rationals between $x-(1/n)$", which made no sense. My first comment was a guess as to what OP meant to write.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right you are. Sorry.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers you have received, 175323?

Comment: I think the problem was more emotional than mathematical. Thank you guys for the answers. I think I'll just use the constructive method from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $y=x+\frac 1n$.

$\Bbb R$ is Archimedian,

$$\exists q>0 \; : \; q(y-x)>100$$

thus

$$qx<qx+100<qy$$

choose $p$ such that

$$qx<p<qx+100<qy$$

thus
$$x<\frac pq<x+\frac 1n$$